# Python - Can't change xmargin in matplotlib / seaborn plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, margin

In the plots that are generated, points appear right on the edge of x axis, so that they are only half visible. I tried modifying xmargins using `plt.rcParams['axes.xmargin']` and `plt.margins(x=0.1, y=0.05)` but nothing seems to modify the xmargin, whereas ymargin does respond to the above settings.

For some reason xmargins in my figures have become immutable. I tried to change them in Jupyter Notebook as well as Spyder, but to no avail.

Here's how it looks.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

np.random.seed(1)
x = np.random.normal(size=100)
y = 2*x + np.random.normal(size=100)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y})
```

**without changing margins**

```
sns.regplot(x='x', y='y', data=df);
# Points appear right at plot edges of the xaxis and are only half visible
```

[image]

**changing y margin only (to 0.65)**

```
plt.margins(x=.05, y=0.65)
sns.regplot(x='x', y='y', data=df)
# ymargin responds to new settings
```

[image]

**trying to change xmargin**

```
plt.margins(x=.65, y=0.05)
sns.regplot(x='x', y='y', data=df)
# xmargin doesn't budge
```

[image]

I have also tried to modify margin with

```
plt.rcParams['axes.xmargin'] = 0.55
ax.margins(x=0.5)
```

Nothing works.

I have to change the xlimits with code for each figure. What can I do to correct this?

Comment: The behavior is related to [sticky edges](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/axes_margins.html?highlight=sticky%20edges). You can use `ax = sns.regplot(...)` and then `ax.use_sticky_edges = False` and `ax.margins(x=0.3, y=0.3)`. The default stickyness is to prevent that the colored band "floats" in the air.  Also for example bar plots have a sticky edge at `y=0`.

Comment: @JohanC Thanks for the explanation. Your suggestion worked.